# import statement in React / Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am in the process of learning React and Gatsby, and I am using styled components in my project. I downloaded the default gatsby project.
My setup is the following, I created a directory called styledComponents, in there I have file called DestkopMenu.js with same styling.

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const StyledHeader = styled.header`
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  background: white;
`
```

Within the same folder I also have index.js that has the following code:

```
export * from "./DesktopMenu"
```

In my components folder I have file called DesktopNav.js where I attempt to import my styled component with the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { StyledHeader } from "../styledComponents"

const DesktopNav = () => {
  return (
    <StyledHeader>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </StyledHeader>
  )
}

export default DesktopNav
```

This fails giving me the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `DesktopNav`.

So, I guess I doing the import statement the wrong way...

When putting the styled components in the same file, it naturaully works with the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import styled from "styled-components"
//import { StyledHeader } from "../styledComponents"

const DesktopNav = () => {
  return (
    <StyledHeader>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </StyledHeader>
  )
}

export default DesktopNav

const StyledHeader = styled.header`
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  background: white;
`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem with your import, but with your export. You did not export `StyledHeader`.

This statement `export * from "./DesktopMenu"` will export all of the named exports from the file `DesktopMenu`. You did not export anything from that file, so therefore the `index.js` will also not export anything.

Simply export the const so that the `index.js` file can find it:

```js
export { StyledHeader };
```